# Regex Get only strings with 3.X

Tags: c#, regex

I have strings like :

```
 - 3.1 TitleA
 - 3.1.1 TitleB
 - 3.1.1.1 TitleC
 - 3.2 TitleD
 - 3.2.1 TitleE
 - 3.2.2 TitleF
 - 3.3 TitleG
```

I would like to only get titles starting with 3.X 
I tried to use (C#) :

```
Match m = Regex.Match(table_of_content[i], "3.[1-999]");
```

But It gave me titles like `3.2.1`
How can I only get titles titles starting with 3.X?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick solution would be:

```
@" 3\.\d+ "
```

This assumes that there is a space before and after the section numbers.

If the assumption applies, this is the simplest solution to avoid matching cases such as:

- `13.2` (other digit appearing before `3`)
- `2.3.2` (`3` is not the highest level section number)
- `3.10.1` (more than 2 levels of sub-section)

Comment: It works perfecly, thank you very much for your quick anwsers guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think he needs only 3.x (not 3.x.x)

```
(?<!\w|\.)3.\d+(?!\w|\.)
```

ok this one then

Comment: Yes 3.x (not 3.x.x) followed by the title name